# initialize again c# variable from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have a c# variable that declare in aspx page and want to Initialize again
it in a `for(;;)` loop.
the loop execute correctly but my c# variable not Initialize again.
what i am doing!!

```
 for (var j = 2; j < '<%=menu[i].Length%>'; j++) {
                                var flag = <%=j++%>
                                alert(flag);
                            }
```

but in below code it is possible

```
for (var j = 2; j < '<%=menu[i].Length%>'; j++) {                               
                                <%j++;%>
                                <%j++;%>
                                var flag = <%=j%>
                                alert(flag);
}
```

Comment: Cannot be done through JavaScript - that code would run on the client side, you cannot manipulate server-side code with it.

Comment: Actually whats your idea behind this to initialize code behind variable in javascript?? I can give you better hint to solve your problem.

Comment: I find it *very* unclear what you are trying to do. Is `j` a C# variable or a JavaScript variable? It looks to me like you are trying to treat it as both.

Answer (score 0):

Alernate way is using hidden field rather than using variable.

```
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn" />

var myVal = document.getElementById("<%= hdn.ClientID %>").value;
for (var j = 2; j < '<%=menu[i].Length%>'; j++)     {                               
    myVal++;
    document.getElementById("<%= hdn.ClientID %>").value = myVal;

}
```

On serverside:

```
int val = int.Parse(hdn.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can initialize your code behind variable in your `.ASPX` page. It is possible using write `FOR` loop also in your `.ASPX` page.

**Code behind variable must be public and member variable of your class:**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     public int i = 0;

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }
}
```

**Javascript Function:**

```
function increaseVariable() {
        <% for (int j = 2; j < menu[i].Length; j++)
           {
            %>
        var flag = <%=i++%>; 
            alert(flag);
        <%}%>
    }
```

**You can test your functionality to add below input button and call above function in onclick event:**

```
<input type="button" value="Increase" onclick="increaseVariable();" />
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.